# predictive distribution of linear bayesian regression with unknow $\Sigma$ and $\Omega$

Tags: regression, nonparametric-bayes

The posterior distribution for weights in linear regression setup is

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
B &| Y,X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \Lambda) \\
\mu &= \Lambda X^{\mathsf{T}}\Sigma^{-1}Y \\
\Lambda &= (X^{\mathsf{T}}\Sigma^{-1}X + \Omega^{-1})^{-1}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

$\Sigma$ is the covariance matrix, $\sigma_{\epsilon}\mathbf{I}$, where $\sigma_{\epsilon}$ is noice on each measurement $y = x \beta + \epsilon$, and $\Omega$ is the covariance on the prior on $\beta$, with $\sigma_{\beta}$ on its diagonal. $B \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma_{\beta})$.

My question is, how to estimate $\Omega$ and $\Sigma$ when both are unknown. Should I assume an iterative process, where every time I replace $\mu$ and $\Lambda$ with $\Sigma$ and $\Omega$ from the previous steps ?

Comment: If $\Sigma$ is unknown it should be associated with a prior. Same thing for $\Omega$.

Comment: I know usually there is a inverse gamma prior. But, in Bishop book (page 153) I do not see such thing.

Comment: There is no "default" priors and [Gelman argues](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/taumain.pdf) that the common Gamma(0.001, 0.001) is not the best choice...

Comment: Thanks for sharing the paper; I am following Bishop book. I don't know if I can provide a link to the book.